# reset() not working when i uploaded a file in live?

Tags: php, ajax

```
$.ajax({
       type:"post",
       url:"pagename.php",
       data:{name:name,email:email,mobile:mobile,message1:message},

       success:function(result)
       {
            //$("#res").html(result);
            if(result==1)
            {
                alert("Message has been sent");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Error!");
            }
       },
       complete:function()
       {
            $('#form').each(function(){
                this.reset();   
            });
       }
    });
```

I have a problem in **reset()** because, i have a clear output in local,but when i tried to work it in live.cannot reset the fields.This makes me very trouble.

Comment: Think the first thing you want to know is, if the ajax call ever completes, or if there is an server-side-error. So have a look in your browsers networking-log.

Comment: @Brainiac: `complete` callback is always invoked, regardless the response result

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding it in complete function as described here

[link is here](http://blog.pratikacharya.com.np/2014/04/11/reset-a-form-using-jquery/)

```
$("#form")[0].reset();
```

Comment: then move it to success function before your if statements

Comment: Do you mean, success:function(result)
     {
       //$("#res").html(result);
    $("#form")[0].reset();
    if(result==1)
    {
     alert("Message has been sent");
    }
    else
    {
     alert("Error!!");
    }
    
     },

Comment: If i add like this,the form will be reseted,then how can i get response ji..i cannot get the msgbox know...

Comment: Need some other suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
 complete:function()
       {

            $("#text-id").val("");
            $("#text1-id").val("");
            $("#text2-id").val("");
            $("#text3-id").val("");
       }
```

Finally i have achieved my desired output by  include the above code,i dont have anyother go.Process moves to **complete:function()**,but **reset()**  doesnot work.So i simply makes the text box value empty!!After submit.

But if any one found the reason for my **reset()** issue inside **complete:function()**  kindly do a comment.